# ReplaceDocumentAsync without Document is that possible?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I query a document and send it to my Angular application. Then I edit the model and send it back. My question is can you update a document from the model only? Document does not have any constructors, and ReplaceDocumentAsync requires Document? Or do I have to query the document first just to get same object i then I have to edit?

```
public void Put([FromBody] VesselView vessel)
{
   var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("AssetControl", "Vessels");
  _cosmosDocClient.ReplaceDocumentAsync(vessel);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** You only have to know the `id` of document you want to replace.
Tested with .Net client Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB v2.2.1.

This can be achieved when **passing the intended new document as `JObject`**. You can use any Json serializer for this. Also, note that your model does not have to contain the internal document fields like `_rid`, `_ts`, etc

Example code:

```
var client = new DocumentClient(url, key, policy);
var documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("myDB", "myCollection", "_replaceTest");

var newModel = JObject.Parse(@"{""id"": ""_replaceTest"",   ""myData"": ""replaced!""}");
var response = await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(documentUri, newModel);
var fromStorage = response.Resource;
```

Returned model is the full model containing the extra model fields:

```
{
  "id": "_replaceTest",
  "_rid": "FOOBAR==",
  "_self": "dbs/FOO==/colls/BAR=/docs/FOOBAR==/",
  "_ts": 1550491238,
  "_etag": "\"0000e379-0000-0000-0000-5c6a9e660000\"",
  "myData": "replaced!"
}
```

Obviously, as David Makogon hinted, you cannot rely on `_etag` check this way, unless you include this property in the model you send to DocumentDB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first retrieve the original document. It contains internal properties such as `_etag` (for concurrency checks) that you wouldn't otherwise have available.